# Angular routing redirect to that same page all time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular2-routing

I have problem with routing in my application. I use Angular2+ and WebApi2. I created Angular from quickstart project and I added it to my WebApi solution. After configurating it, I launched first time app allthing work fine. Problems appear after I added routing. When I try to navigate to link included in routing table, the browser redirect me all time to one component. I searched how to deal with it but I didn't find anything. Below I present codes and file names:

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
     routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**Share _Layout.cshtml**

```
<script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="~/src/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('./src/main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

**system.config.js**

```
packages: {
  app: {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    meta: {
      './*.js': {
        loader: '/src/systemjs-angular-loader.js'
      }
    }
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from './HomePage.component';
import { Test } from './Test.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomePage },
    { path: 'test', component: Test },
    { path: '**', component: HomePage }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent, HomePage, Test
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [HomePage]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Index.cshtml**
    `<home-page></home-page>`

Comment: replace <home-page></home-page> by <app-root></app-root> in your index

Comment: What is it change when I bootstrap `HomePage`? Now I see in console `The selector "home-page" did not match any elements`

Comment: your index is the enter point is has to containe only <app-root></app-root>  and bootstrap: [HomePage] will load HomePage  component

Comment: and your HomePage must contain <router-outlet></router-outlet> to load your routes

Comment: As you said, I added to `HomePage` `<router-outlet>` byt I still see in the console that same error: `The selector "home-page" did not match any elements`

Comment: where do you have home-page?

Comment: I had it in Index.cshtml. I resolved problem, thanks.

Comment: you have to delete it from there

Answer (score 1):

Answer: all problems are caused by `@RenderBody()`. When I moved `<home-page></home-page>` under `@RenderBody()` all is working fine.